# A monoid where square of all elements are 1 is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

The following problem gives me a very hard time:

> Let $M$ be a monoid with $a^2 = 1$ for $a \in M$. Show that $M$ is abelian.

It looks so simple as a monoid only needs to be associative and must have a neutral element (here $1$). So there are not much things to try. However, after some hours of trying I have to admit that I don't know what to try next.

Maybe somebody of you can give me a hint.

Kind regards!

Comment: Your title is misleading. An element $a$ is idempotent if $a^2 = a$, not if $a^2 = 1$.

Comment: Calling it a monoid is a red herring: obviously it is a group, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1=abab\to b=ababb \to b=aba \to ab =aaba \to ab =ba $